# ECONNRESET(Connection reset by peer)

Tags: c#, android, connection

Does someone know what happen when i receive this error, I am lock for some hours on this problem. My code is :

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVICE_DATA_ADRESSE);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
```

On the server side the method call is working well when i debug it (It is a Csharp server)

When the code run i receive this error

```
ECONNRESET(Connection reset by peer)
```

but i have no idea what does it really mean. Does someone can translate to me this error ?

Thanks,

Eliott

Answer (score 0):

It was due to a problem in serialisation when the server want to send the answer.